# Bind Multiple SPARQL Variables into One

Tags: sparql

Is there a way of doing something like this:

```
BIND((?s1, ?s2, ?s3) AS ?s)
```

such that queries on ?s will be distributed to the list?

**EDIT**

BTW, it seems the following does not work.  Am I doing something wrong?

```
SELECT *
WHERE
{
  VALUES (?s1 ?s2 ?s3) {(1 4 7) (2 5 8) (3 6 9)} .
  {
    {
      BIND(?s1 AS ?s)
    }
    union
    {
      BIND(?s2 AS ?s)
    }
    union
    {
      BIND(?s3 AS ?s)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have concrete values to use for `?s`, then you can [VALUES](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#inline-data) in SPARQL 1.1.  If you don't have concrete values, then you may still be able to do this if you can structure your query so that `?s` is generated by a subquery.  I'll give an example of each, using this data:

```
@prefix : <http://example.org/> .

:t :hasEss :s1, :s2, :s3  .
:s1 :value "larry" .
:s2 :value "curly" .
:s3 :value "moe" .
```

#### Using `VALUES`

`VALUES` specifies fixed values for one or more variables.

```
prefix : <http://example.org/>

select * where { 
  values ?s { :s1 :s2 :s3 }
  ?s :value ?value
}

$ arq --data data.n3 --query values.query
-----------------
| s   | value   |
=================
| :s1 | "larry" |
| :s2 | "curly" |
| :s3 | "moe"   |
-----------------
```

We're only using one (`?s`) here, but the syntax also supports more, so in the future, if you have need for it, you can also do

```
values (?x ?y) { (:x1 :y1) (:x2 :y2) ... }
```

#### Using a subquery

You could also write a subquery that finds the values of `?s` and then the superquery will use those results.

```
prefix : <http://example.org/>

select * where { 
  { 
    select ?s where { 
      :t :hasEss ?s
    }
  }
  ?s :value ?value
}

$ arq --data data.n3 --query subquery.sparql
-----------------
| s   | value   |
=================
| :s3 | "moe"   |
| :s2 | "curly" |
| :s1 | "larry" |
-----------------
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was wondering more in the case that there were variables already bound; I suppose I could do as you state with the subquery, bind what would be bound to ?s1,2,3 directly to ?s, but I may need to keep the bindings for ?s1,2,3 as well as have them in ?s.  Doing like above would mean losing distinct bindings.  Prepare to be assimilated?

Comment: @NargothBond  I think I follow what you mean, but I'm not exactly sure.  Could you update your question with an example of what you'd _like_ be to able to do, that is, an example of the code that you could _ideally_ write (even though it isn't _actually_ legal)?  From that we might be able to better pin down what can be done to simulate it.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are using the VALUES keyword correctly, but I suspect that there is a short coming in your engine. Are you using SESAME?

However you can work around it by using the BIND coupled with UNION (again!)

```
SELECT *
WHERE
{
    {
        BIND(1 as ?s1)
        BIND(4 as ?s2)
        BIND(7 as ?s3)
    }
    union
    {
        BIND(2 as ?s1)
        BIND(5 as ?s2)
        BIND(8 as ?s3)
    }
    union
    {
        BIND(3 as ?s1)
        BIND(6 as ?s2)
        BIND(9 as ?s3)
    }

    {
        {
            BIND(?s1 AS ?s)
        }
        union
        {
            BIND(?s2 AS ?s)
        }
        union
        {
            BIND(?s3 AS ?s)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks again, and begging your pardon, but are you actually testing these?  The added bindings with the numbers is invalid syntax, and doesn't seem to contribute anything.  Now, I am using Fuseki, so that could be the problem.

Comment: Whoops, I got the BIND statement around the wrong way and left the VALUES statement in there. This is now tested under sesame. Sorry if I mucked you about at all.

Comment: Hmmm... it still doesn't seem to bind to ?s....  I could be asking for the impossible with my system.  At any rate, I can just query twice and probably get what I need.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could give a worked example.

As you asked it I don't think that it is possible as binding can be bound to a single entity at any one time. The previous poster has given an excellent response although I have found the VALUES support to be lacking in some engines. An alternative way of writing the query in the absence of the VALUES keyword is to make use of UNION.

```
select ?s {

    # some query that results a binding to ?s1 ?s2 and \ or ?s3

    {
       BIND(?s1 AS ?s)
    }
    union
    {
       BIND(?s2 AS ?s)
    }
    union
    {
       BIND(?s3 AS ?s)
    }
}
```

This will merge the results from ?s1 ?s2 and ?s3 into a single "column" in your sparql output.

However this is poor form, and I suggest that you restructure your query so that this 'trick' is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem to work for me (I have edited my question with code to test it).  Am I doing something wrong, or does it not work on my system (Fuseki)?

Answer (score 0):

I did

```
select .. ?name WHERE {

  OPTIONAL { ?component fosschema:A.name ?name }
  OPTIONAL { ?component fosschema:B.name ?name }

}
GROUP BY ...?name
```

knowing that only one of them will be found